# Adding local user SSL certificate (.crt) to all Java stores on Windows PC

Tags: java, powershell, cmd

I wrote the following windows power shell script in order to add my crt SSL certificate to all java cacert stores

```
$certs = @(Get-Childitem -Path "C:\Program files" -Include *cacerts* -Exclude *.pem -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue);$keytool = Get-Childitem -Path "C:\Program files" -filter keytool.exe -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select -First 1; foreach ( $cert in $certs ){& "$keytool" -import -trustcacerts -alias mycert-ca$(date -format dMyyhm) -file C:\Path\to\my-crt.crt -keystore $cert -storepass changeit -noprompt}
```

the problem is that when I try to run it on anything more than program files the search takes a very long time.
when I am searching in the command prompt with the following command `dir c:\ /s /b | findstr -i cacerts` I get results for the whole c drive within a minute.

is there any equivalent command for ps?

Comment: Well, you should really be using `-Filter`. Also, PowerShell will tend to be slower as there isn't so much overhead when working with text shells. You're also not excluding in your cmd call which will be faster overall.

Comment: thanks @AbrahamZinala it looks like the exclusions were the main fault.
actually, after I changed to filter and removed the asterisks it wasn't needed anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post here my script updated after the comments I got on my question I checked it on my pc and it worked perfectly.

```
$certs = @(Get-Childitem –Path "C:\Program files", "C:\Program Files (x86)" -Filter cacerts -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue);$keytool = Get-Childitem -Path "C:\Program files", "C:\Program Files (x86)" -Filter keytool.exe -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select -First 1; foreach ( $cert in $certs ){& "$keytool" -import -trustcacerts -alias myCert$(date -format dMyyhm) -file C:\Path\to\CA\myCertificate.crt -keystore $cert -storepass changeit -noprompt}
```

make sure to change the `-file C:\Path\to\CA\myCertificate.crt` to your certificate path. and the `-alias myCert$(date -format dMyyhm)` to a name of your choice.

The `$(date -format dMyyhm)` is there in case you want to have an option to update the certificate without deleting the old on, if that is not the case you can remove this part.

in the enclosed version I was searching only in the two program files directories because as far as I know, that's where all Java containing files are located but you can change the -path flag to point to "C:\" or even "\" for me it took 2 minutes on a 1TB entire drive.

Comment: If so then you may want to mark this as the answer.

Comment: I have to wait two days for that (those are the rules for self answers)